# applying melt in a loop

Tags: r, reshape

I have a list of dataframes, and I would like to melt and then add a column with a factor (here set).
And then ultimately combine.  However, I am getting an error trying to use melt with lapply (I will do list with do.call, rbind) but I"m stuck at the apply melt.

Any help is appreciated, and maybe I'm not passing 'set' correctly.

```
Melt<-function(df,set){
df_mlt<-melt(df)
colnames(df_mlt)<-c("pt","col","Int")
df_mlt<-transform(df_mlt,set=rep(set,times=dim(df_mlt)[1]))
}
files_mlted<-lapply(names(files_shifted),function(x) Melt(files_shifted[[x]],x))

Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

---

```
> str(files_shifted)
List of 3
 $ EcEcDelta      : num [1:45, 1:12] NA NA NA 4184 4198 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:12] "line 1" "line 2" "line 3" "line 4" ...
 $ MesecMesecDelta: num [1:46, 1:7] 4708 4679 4674 4747 4717 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:7] "line 1" "line 2" "line 3" "line 4" ...
 $ MesecMesDelta  : num [1:51, 1:12] NA NA 4408 4472 4581 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:12] "line 1" "line 2" "line 3" "line 4" ...



structure(list(EcEcDelta = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 4183.9897, 
4197.9263, 4169.5312, 4164.3252, 4413.3159, 4396.481, 4155.8994, 
4110.7871, 4296.3462, 4497.458, 4516.624, 4597.8345, 4680.0024, 
4800.0811, 4992.167, 5375.4189, 5933.1914, 6589.8003, 7691.2852, 
8650.3418, 8643.0215, 7475.228, 6215.3271, 5240.209, 4646.1699, 
4358.4946, 4203.7007, 4200.9126, 4292.7974, 4290.2119, 4035.3877, 
3824.6089, 3694.5603, 3794.0649, 3835.3845, 3743.8027, 3839.2417, 
3944.7722, 3975.55, 3994.0811, 4193.9482, 4220.0361, NA, NA, 
, NA), .Dim = c(45L, 12L), .Dimnames = list(
NULL, c("line 1", "line 2", "line 3", "line 4", "line 5", 
"line 6", "line 7", "line 8", "line 9", "line 10", "line 11", 
"line 12"))), MesecMesecDelta = structure(c(4708.2158, 4678.9521, 
4674.4448, 4747.0122, 4717.1528, 4855.1533, 4823.2969, 4729.3257, 
4474.9043, 4478.2461, 4659.1538, 4626.4385, 4698.3784, 4795.8794, 
4914.1973, 5186.6772, 5517.021, 5717.6484, 6304.8179, 7310.9424, 
8474.2725, 9362.792, 9325.4678, 8488.7021, 7503.6167, 7087.0112,  
4211.4683, 4333.1514, 4346.751, 4350.1226, 4115.3848, 3880.6357, 
3890.1731, 3747.5061, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(46L, 
7L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("line 1", "line 2", "line 3", "line 4", 
"line 5", "line 6", "line 7"))), MesecMesDelta = structure(c(NA, 
NA, 4407.7998, 4471.9248, 4581.3101, 4618.3403, 4529.812, 4604.5894, 
4775.9009, 4824.9214, 4684.2368, 4594.7852, 4447.998, 4347.6182, 
4370.4023, 4211.9419, 4262.7798, 4381.9023, 4452.2407, 4653.1538, 
4997.3403, 5659.2056, 6694.8037, 7665.9014, 7676.9712, 7077.6855, 
3600.1545, 3739.146, 3968.1042, 4155.644, 4273.3623, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3955.3906, 3826.8286, 
3217.3462, 3034.8352, 2965.7563, 3042.1465, 3121.8101, 3150.625, 
3139.7209, 3178.7612, 3373.1699, 3699.7705, 3920.2891, 3914.2915, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(51L, 12L), .Dimnames = list(
NULL, c("line 1", "line 2", "line 3", "line 4", "line 5", 
"line 6", "line 7", "line 8", "line 9", "line 10", "line 11", 
"line 12")))), .Names = c("EcEcDelta", "MesecMesecDelta", 
"MesecMesDelta"))
```

Comment: @AnandaMahto you are correct, but this is not producing the error

Comment: Thanks for the `dput` output.  But it gives error. `Error in c(NA, NA, NA, 4183.9897, 4197.9263, 4169.5312, 4164.3252, 4413.3159,  : 
  argument 48 is empty`

Comment: The dimensions of the `dput` data is not matching with the elements.  So, I changed the dataset a bit.  Please check if the posted solution helps.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, your example dataset is not correct.  It gives me error to start with.  Please copy and paste the dput output you posted on the R console and see if the error pops up.  Secondly, please show `set`.  Is it a vector?  If so, do you want to create the column like I showed in the second option?

Comment: Can you try this on a fresh R console?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
library(reshape2)
set <- 'A'
res <- transform(do.call(`rbind`,lapply(lst, melt)), set=set)
row.names(res) <- NULL
```

Suppose, you have multiple elements in `set` (length equal to length of `lst`) and want to create a new column in each list element for the corresponding `set` element

```
set <- LETTERS[1:3]
res1 <- do.call(`rbind`,Map(cbind, lapply(lst, melt), set=set))
row.names(res1) <- NULL
head(res1,3)
#   Var1   Var2 value set
#1    1 line 1    NA   A
#2    2 line 1    NA   A
#3    3 line 1    NA   A
```

#### data

```
lst <- structure(list(EcEcDelta = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 4183.9897, 
4197.9263, 4169.5312, 4164.3252, 4413.3159, 4396.481, 4155.8994, 
4110.7871, 4296.3462, 4497.458, 4516.624, 4597.8345, 4680.0024, 
4800.0811, 4992.167, 5375.4189, 5933.1914, 6589.8003, 7691.2852, 
8650.3418, 8643.0215, 7475.228, 6215.3271, 5240.209, 4646.1699, 
4358.4946, 4203.7007, 4200.9126, 4292.7974, 4290.2119, 4035.3877, 
3824.6089, 3694.5603, 3794.0649, 3835.3845, 3743.8027, 3839.2417, 
3944.7722, 3975.55, 3994.0811, 4193.9482, 4220.0361, NA, NA,NA),
.Dim = c(4L, 12L), .Dimnames = list(NULL,
c("line 1", "line 2", "line 3", "line 4", "line 5", 
"line 6", "line 7", "line 8", "line 9", "line 10", "line 11", 
"line 12"))), MesecMesecDelta = structure(c(4708.2158, 4678.9521, 
4674.4448, 4747.0122, 4717.1528, 4855.1533, 4823.2969, 4729.3257, 
4474.9043, 4478.2461, 4659.1538, 4626.4385, 4698.3784, 4795.8794, 
4914.1973, 5186.6772, 5517.021, 5717.6484, 6304.8179, 7310.9424, 
8474.2725, 9362.792, 9325.4678, 8488.7021, 7503.6167, 7087.0112,  
4211.4683, 4333.1514, 4346.751, 4350.1226, 4115.3848, 3880.6357, 
3890.1731, 3747.5061, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(6L, 
7L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("line 1", "line 2", "line 3", "line 4", 
"line 5", "line 6", "line 7"))), MesecMesDelta = structure(c(NA, 
NA, 4407.7998, 4471.9248, 4581.3101, 4618.3403, 4529.812, 4604.5894, 
4775.9009, 4824.9214, 4684.2368, 4594.7852, 4447.998, 4347.6182, 
4370.4023, 4211.9419, 4262.7798, 4381.9023, 4452.2407, 4653.1538, 
4997.3403, 5659.2056, 6694.8037, 7665.9014, 7676.9712, 7077.6855, 
3600.1545, 3739.146, 3968.1042, 4155.644, 4273.3623, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3955.3906, 3826.8286, 
3217.3462, 3034.8352, 2965.7563, 3042.1465, 3121.8101, 3150.625, 
3139.7209, 3178.7612, 3373.1699, 3699.7705, 3920.2891, 3914.2915, 
NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(5L, 12L), .Dimnames = list(
NULL, c("line 1", "line 2", "line 3", "line 4", "line 5", 
"line 6", "line 7", "line 8", "line 9", "line 10", "line 11", 
"line 12")))), .Names = c("EcEcDelta", "MesecMesecDelta", 
"MesecMesDelta"))
```

Comment: > res1 <- do.call(`rbind`,Map(cbind, lapply(lst, melt), set=set))
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?

Comment: @user2814482 Are you saying you tried the code on original dataset and got he error or on the data I posted?

Comment: @akrun Here is another good example to learn the functions. I will have a close look this weekend. :)

Comment: @jazzurro No problem.  Glad it is helping you.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, late answer, but I thought I'd add it for those in a similar situation.  As I saw a few similar unanswered questions.

I had previously, called my function 'melt' instead of Melt.  and this had written over the function 'melt from reshape2' therefore it was stuck in an infinte loop.

so be careful of naming your own functions,the same name as a base R function.